# Github Actions Reusable Workflows Secrets Not working

Tags: github, microservices, github-actions, cicd

I have a simple scenario with reusable workflows and secrets which doesn't work as the secrets are empty.

I have 3 GH repositories:

1. Microservice code - contains the code to runs the workflows from the domain gh actions repo
2. Domain GH Workflows repo - contains the github action secrets for the domain and uses the reusable workflows from the core devops repository
3. Core GH Workflows repo - contains generic workflows with many parameters that could be passed by other repositories

I have added the domain secrets (such as aws access key and aws secret access key) to the domain Domain GH Workflows and passed it with the named secrets to the given workflow using the tutorial from the GH - I do not want to use the "inherit" keyword, as i have to use the parametrized version.

However, only the empty strings are passed, even though I have added those kyes to the Github Repository Secrets of the Domain repository.
I have tried also adding it to the environment and using the environment value in the workflows in any part of the flow (microservice repo and domain gh workflow repo).

Do you have any idea of why is it happening and what could be done to fix the problems that I am facing or achieve the similar results with a different approach?

Comment: If you don't want to use the inherit keyword, you need to set each secret in the reusable workflow `workflow_call` trigger configuration, and share each secret from the main workflow (calling the reusable) as secrets inputs.

Comment: Have already done that - the problem is that the secrets are passed as empty strings and not the real values

Comment: Could you share the workflows in the question to reproduce the issue? 

Comment: I think I have found the problem. When you have the flow repo A (job which started) -> repo B (reusable workflow) -> repo C (reusable workflow), you cannot use secrets from the repository B and C, but only from an A. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can only use secrets from the repository workflow calling the reusable workflow.

Comment: That solves the problem - on the other hand, do you know any way to unify the secrets? If i am deploying 5 microservices to the same AWS account that uses the same role, etc it would be really useful to have the access keys saved only in one repository instead of 5

Comment: In that case, I guess the eqsiest solution would be to create an Organization, and use Organization Secrets to share those secrets in different repository, storing them in only one place.

Comment: Well, that could be the solution - however then we would have to share the secrets even with other teams which work also on AWS and have to rename the secrets appropriately - such as TEAM_A_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, and then reusing the workflows would create some more overhead. Nevertheless the problem is solved :) if you want you can add the answer with sharing the secrets only in the root repository which I would approve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't want to use the `inherit` keyword, you need to set each secret in the reusable workflow `workflow_call` trigger configuration, and share each secret from the main workflow (calling the reusable) as secrets inputs.

However, in that case, you can only use secrets from the repository workflow calling the reusable workflow.

*Note: If you want to avoid duplicating secrets between repositories, there is also the solution of using Organization Secrets to share those secrets in different repository, storing them in only one place.*